# How can i include all recent updates during kickstart install on fedora/centos without %post

Tags: centos, fedora, kickstart, installer-anaconda

A standard install with a kickstart file on fedora or centos just installs the packages from the install repository, which are usually outdated after some days after the release of a new fedora/centos version. So installing a fedora/centos always requires a %post section in the kickstart file where you would call a dnf/yum update -y  in order to upgrade the old and outdated packages. 
This is a waste of time and bandwidth and  the dnf/yum installer can use multiple repositories at the same time and pick the latest version.

How can I tell anaconda during a fresh install to include the "updates" repository for installation, so that a yum/dnf update -y afterwards is not required, as the updates woud already be installed?

Comment: Did you try the `repo` option of [kickstart](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-options.html)?

Comment: oh my, not sure why i did overlook this option - will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any recent version of Fedora, Anaconda comes with built-in configuration for the `updates` repo. So you should be able to enable updates in a Fedora install just by adding the line:

```
repo --name=updates
```

to your kickstart. From the [kickstart documentation of the `repo` command](http://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#repo):

> By default, anaconda has a configured set of repos taken from
>   /etc/anaconda.repos.d plus a special Installation Repo in the case of
>   a media install. The exact set of repos in this directory changes from
>   release to release and cannot be listed here. There will likely always
>   be a repo named “updates”.
>
> Note: If you want to enable one of the repos in /etc/anaconda.repos.d
>   that is disabled by default (like “updates”), you should use –name=
>   but none of the other options. anaconda will look for a repo by this
>   name automatically. Providing a baseurl or mirrorlist URL will result
>   in anaconda attempting to add another repo by the same name, which
>   will cause a conflicting repo error.

That shortcut should work fine in CentOS 7 (thanks to @maxschlepzig in the comments for checking!). If you have to deal with something older you should still be able to add the `updates` repo manually with a more complete `repo` command:

```
repo --name=centos-updates --mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
```

That would enable the CentOS updates repo (with full mirror support!) during the install.

Comment: would be wonderful for completion sake to know which one actually worked..

Comment: @AlexR, I've just tested `repo --name=updates` with `CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1810.iso` and it *does work*. That means the `ks.cfg` is accepted and a `yum update` after first reboot doesn't want to update anything.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this question hoping for a solution that works with CentOS 8.x, I found adding these lines will do the trick:

```
repo --name=centos-updates --mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS --cost=1000
repo --name=appstream-updates --mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=AppStream --cost=1000
repo --name=extras-updates --mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=Extras --cost=1000
```

The same should work with RHEL 8, with appropriate modifications and system registration, etc...